# Получение товаров из категории в Allegro с помощью API

Tags: php, rest

Всем привет.
Есть задача получить список продуктов (предложений/обьявлений) в категории из allegro с помощью их API.
Я подключаюсь, получаю токен, далее получаю категории, но после этого получаю ошибку:

```
$response   = $client->request( 'GET', 'https://api.allegro.pl/offers/listing', [
                        'headers' => [
                            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
                            'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.allegro.public.v1+json'
                        ],
                    ] );
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Exception: Client error: `GET https://api.allegro.pl/offers/listing` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: {"errors":[{"code":"VerificationRequired","message":"Access is denied. Verification is required.","details":null,"path": (truncated...)
```

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался? Куда копать?
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Может ваш аккаунт еще какую-то проверку не прошел? Скорее всего при прочтении целого лога там будет -- "userMessage":"Access denied. Access available only for verified applications."

Comment: спасибо. уже написал в поддержку аллегро

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['allegro_tokens'])) {
            $accessToken = $_SESSION['allegro_tokens']['access_token'];
        } else {
            header('Location: ' . getUrl('allegro'));
            
        }
        $params = [
            'limit' => 1000
        ];

        $queryString = http_build_query($params);

        $url = 'https://api.allegro.pl/sale/offers';
        $urlWithParams = $url . '?' . $queryString;


        // Ініціалізуйте cURL
        $ch = curl_init();
        // Встановіть налаштування cURL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlWithParams);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Accept: application/vnd.allegro.public.v1+json',
            'Content-Type: application/vnd.allegro.public.v1+json',
            'Accept-Language: pl-PL'
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Перевірте наявність помилок
        if ($response === false) {
            die('cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Закрийте cURL
        curl_close($ch);
        $offers = json_decode($response, true);

        foreach ($offers['offers'] as $marketplaceProduct) {
            if ($marketplaceProduct) {
```

вот таким образом я получил список товаров, можно установил лимит в 1000, так же можно зная айди категории прописать и доставать товары только данной категории, в документации метода сказано что можно прописывать доп параметры, такие как "цена от", "цена до" и тд